# Minimum number of balls to obtain accurate information about a bipartition of the bin set

Tags: co.combinatorics

We have a set of $n^2$ bins, partitioned into two subsets: $A\neq\emptyset$ and $B\neq\emptyset$. Assume $n$ goes to infinity.

We continue to throw balls independently and uniformly at random into the $n^2$ bins, until $\log(n)$ balls are placed in bins belonging to subset $A$, then we stop. Let $m$ be the total number of balls we have thrown.

**Questions**: What is the minimum cardinality of $A$ such that
$$\frac{m}{\log n}=\Theta\left(\frac{n^2}{|A|}\right)$$ holds w.h.p.?

Comment: Your second paragraph says how many balls we have to throw, then your question asks how many balls we have to throw.  I'm confused.

Comment: Sorry Brendan, you are right.

Comment: You might find this simpler if you strip away some of the unnecessary decoration: replace $n^2$ by $n$, and the size of $A$ by a per-round success probability.  Then you're looking for $p = p(n)$ such that $m = \Theta\left(\frac {\log n} p\right)$.

Comment: Thanks, you are right Ben Barber, but now I already received an answer which incorporates the modifications you suggested. Hence, I would not modify the problem text now, to avoid a "mismatch" with the answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a form of law of large numbers, and Chernoff's bound seems to work.

Denote $n_A/n^2=p$, $\log n=k$, then we deal with Bernoulli i.i.d. $\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots$, $\xi_i\in \{0,1\}$, $\mathbb{E} \xi_i=p$, and $m$ is the minimal number for which $\xi_1+\dots+\xi_m\geqslant k$.

Then the event $\{m\geqslant cp^{-1}k\}$ is just the event $\{\sum_{j\leqslant cp^{-1}k} \xi_j< k\}$. You ask when this is event has small probability for large enough constant $c$. I claim that it is so for any $p>0$.

The probability of this event equals the sum of coefficients of $x^j,j>k$, in the polynomial $F(x)=(px+(1-p))^{[cp^{-1}k]}$. The sum of such coefficients does not exceed $x^{-k}F(x)$ for any $x<1$. Take $x=(1-p)/(c-p)$ (this value is suggested by equating the derivative to 0.) We get $$(px+1-p)^{c/p}x^{-1}=(cx)^{c/p}x^{-1}=c\left(1-\frac{p(c-1)}{c-p}\right)^{c/p-1}\sim ce^{1-c}:=\rho<1$$
for fixed $c>1$. Thus $x^{-k}F(x)<\rho^k$ tends to 0.